# Как получить всю информацию из onCreateContextMenu

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Есть работающий код, который приведен ниже. В ListView отображаются имена. Как получить не только contact_id контакта, а и само имя контакта в виде String name. Буду признателен за ответ.

```
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, CM_LOOK_ID, 0, R.string.contacts_list);        
    menu.add(0, CM_DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.delete_record);
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case CM_LOOK_ID:
            String all_id = String.valueOf(acmi.id);
            Intent intent8 = new Intent(this, ActivityLook.class);
            intent8.putExtra("all_id", all_id);
            startActivity(intent8);
            break;            
        case CM_DELETE_ID:
            contact_id = String.valueOf(acmi.id);
            delD();
            Intent intent9 = new Intent(this, ActivityAllContacts.class);
            startActivity(intent9);
            break;
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Взять айтем по `id` или позиции из адаптера или списка, а из него уже имя и что хотите. Что-то вроде: `String name = getListView().getItemAtPosition(acmi.position);` (абстрактный пример).

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже нашел ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    contact_id = String.valueOf(info.id);
    menu.add(0, CM_LOOK_ID, 0, R.string.contact_list);        
    menu.add(0, CM_DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.delete_record);
```

а затем по contact_id из таблицы BD взял имя.